# Children's/YA Sci-Fi novel where kids steal spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, space, childrens-novel

I'm trying to remember a sci-fi novel, probably from the 80's or 90's, I read the first few chapters of in 5th grade. In it two kids, a girl and a boy, steal a spaceship from their school. They go into space and get held-up and captured by some aliens with freeze rays, this was as far as I got in the book. The book was written in first person from the perspective of the girl, and it had a comedic tone. The two kids had a crush on each other.

Some other things I remember:

- The parents of the girl were either astronauts of some other kind of scientists
- The parents worked for some organization that's name was NASA but with one or two extra letters, like CNASA or something
- Ganymede had been turned into a retirement community
- I think the school was in Mexico, but I might be conflating this with some other book
- The kids took the spaceship on the last day of school before vacation
- Earth had established diplomatic relations with alien life forms
- Shortly after being captured, the girl tries using an alien toilet but is confused how it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this would be *I Spent my Summer Vacation Kidnapped into Space* by Martyn N. Godfrey. The name of the space organization was NASA-O (the "O" probably standing for "offworld;" I don't have the book on hand at the moment to check). I do recommend it, a lot of interesting stuff happens after the point you stopped reading.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] your post to add some more info about this book, e.g. details that match the description in the question?

Comment: That's it, thanks.